# How to grep inverted not showing x lines before/after?

Tags: text-processing, grep

What I need is easy to explain but couldn't do it :-( 
I want to grep a command output **not showing the matching lines and x lines after** that. Eg.

```
# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/ram0: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram1: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

I want to skip lines with 'ram' string and 6 lines after that, so the output would be just:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

Something like `sudo fdisk -l | grep -v "ram" -A 6`

Comment: The reason it doesn't do what you expect is that `-v` just inverts the pattern, not the set of lines that ultimately get printed.

Comment: Since the `fdisk` output appears to consist of blank-line separated records, a "paragraph mode" approach using `awk` or `perl` might be more straightforward e.g. `fdisk -l | awk -vRS= '! /ram/'`

Comment: why not just `fdisk -l /dev/sda`

Comment: `sed '/ram/,+5 d'`

Comment: `grep -A 6 /dev/sd` may achieve what you're after.

Comment: @val0x00ff That's the point, I want to display just "sdX devs" and all of them but without the "rams" ;-)

Comment: @DamonHill Have you heard of globs? `fdisk -l /dev/sd*` or  character range `fdisk -l /dev/sd[a-f]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach with GNU sed:

```
| sed '/ram/,/^$/d;/^$/d'
```

Output:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```