# "grep -A" but with some lines removed

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed, grep

## The problem

The output of `grep -A 4 davidson file.txt` gives me:

```
davidson 0 27  |r|= 0.00244  e= [-0.04073962  0.42777949  0.44157777  0.45997235  0.45997235  0.51613738 
  0.55005554  0.5538866   0.5538866   0.57108874  0.63182267  0.68741162
  0.68741186  0.69608     0.78013465  0.78013465  0.78042162  0.78688599
  0.78688599  0.79381315  0.79381317  0.80049466  0.80049466  0.92062423
  0.93453524  1.01356402  1.01942272]  max|de|= 1.02  lindep= 0.809
--
davidson 1 54  |r|= 3.26  e= [-0.04073964  0.42777928  0.44157749  0.45997213  0.45997213  0.51613724
  0.55005542  0.55388652  0.55388652  0.57108822  0.63182247  0.68741026
  0.68741031  0.69607963  0.78013252  0.78013252  0.78042159  0.78688546
  0.78688546  0.793812    0.793812    0.80049354  0.80049354  0.92062408
  0.93453361  0.97904591  1.01356325  1.01945088]  max|de|= -0.0404  lindep= 0.694
--
davidson 2 66  |r|= 0.523  e= [-0.04073964  0.02576398  0.42777928  0.44157749  0.45997212  0.45997212
  0.51613724  0.55005542  0.55388652  0.55388652  0.57108822  0.63182247
  0.68741006  0.68741006  0.69607962  0.78013218  0.78013218  0.78042159
  0.78688546  0.78688546  0.79381179  0.79381179  0.80049292  0.80049292
  0.92062408  0.93453351  1.01356275  1.01942294]  max|de|= -0.953  lindep= 0.278
```

***What if for each of the above three groups of output, I only want the first and last line?*** Specifically, rather than getting lines 1-5 for each instance of the string `davidson`, I want to get only lines 1 and 5.

## Prior research I've attempted

I have searched:

> "grep -A" but with some lines removed

using Google and the search bar here in unix.se, and didn't get many results (especially the latter search, which only gave me [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/328210/78288)). These were some of the results I found from the Google search, and reasons why they don't seem to solve my problem:

- Unix.SE: [grep files with pattern A but exclude files with pattern B](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/523716/78288) (I don't actually know what pattern to exclude, since it's different every time).
- StackOverflow: [Grep ignore multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1491647/1271772) (the answers very "hardcoded" to for the specific data provided in the question, and don't contain explanations).
- StackOverflow: [Combine -v option for grep with -A option](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38895234/1271772) (the answers very "hardcoded" to for the specific data provided in the question).
- StackOverflow: [Extract Nth line after matching pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18185771/1271772) (this is similar, but different from what I'm asking).
- StackOverflow: [Skipping lines in Grep](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37603662/1271772) (this is getting closer, but isn't exactly what I'm asking either).

When typing this question, the following question was suggested to me:

- Unix.SE: [Where is the "group-separator" option listed in the grep documentation?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/460535/78288), which refers to:
- StackOverflow: [How do I get rid of "--" line separator when using grep with context lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2168065/1271772)

But neither of these solve my problem either.

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input (contents of `file.txt` rather than the output of running `grep -A` on that file) and expected output so we can help you. The right solution won't involve `grep` so just seeing the `grep` output isn't adequate to figure out what that solution might be.

Comment: Your original file appears to be structured in some way. It would be interesting to see more of it to give you a way of working with that original file directly instead of with a pre-processed version of it. If you can additionally let us know what produced the data, someone may know of a parser for that specific format.

Comment: (cont.) Also, the first and last line of each group in the output seems to contain parts of an array. If you let us know _exactly_ what you want to get (like the `|r|` value and the `max|de|` value or something), it may be easier for us to give you an answer that does not require _further_ post-processing steps on your end.

Comment: @Kusalananda please give me some time to add those details okay?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you didn't give us a sample of the original data, but playing with your output above this may do what you want?

Rather than `grep -A4 ...` try this:

```
awk '/davidson/{h=NR;line=$0} NR==h+4{print line;print $0}' file.txt
```

Comment: +1 but could be shortened a bit to `awk '/davidson/{h=NR; print}; NR==h+4 && h'`.    The `&& h` avoids printing the 4th input line when NR=4 and h hasn't been set yet (h won't be true until it is non-zero, which it won't be until an input line matches `/davidson/`).

Comment: `'/davidson/{h=NR+4; print} NR==h'` is a bit more concise and avoids printing line number 4 if/when `davidson` doesn't occur in the first 4 lines of input.